# Parsing and saving a JSON sub-array in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, activerecord

I have a JSON feed that I'm saving to the database, and within the array of data, there is a property that's an array:

```
{
   "reports": [
      {
         "name1":"val1",
         "name2":"val2",
         "sub": [
            {"x":9,"y":-8,"z":134},
            {"x":10,"y":-7,"z":136}
         ]
       }
    ]
}
```

The sub-array values will be saved into its own table so my question is: how can I easily insert the parent records, get the identity of the newly created record, and then save the sub-array records?

This is what I have so far, but as you could guess, the id of the sub-array values is nil.

```
rpts = metrics['reports']
saved_reports = Report.create rpts do |r|
   if (r.sub != nil) then
      SubReport.create r.sub do |a|
         # How do I get the ID of the parent record?
         a.report_id = r.id
      end
   end
end
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What about just saving the report first, then check for the sub array in a `if saved_reports.save` block and create it there?

Comment: That would work if the parent was only one record, but the parent is also an array so I'm inserting multiple items. How would I best resolve the parent with the subarrays? Would I just loop back through saved_reports again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how many attributes your Report has, maybe something like this would be practical

```
rpts = metrics['reports']
rpts.each do |r|
  report = Report.new name1: r.name1, name2: r.name2
  if report.save && !r.sub.nil?
    # save sub report here
  end
end
```